# On the Overwatch Network Graph, what does each value means?

Tags: pc, overwatch

On the PC version of Overwatch, if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> you will open the Network Graph.

In there, you will see some obvious values like the server that you are playing in (in this case, sae1 is Brazil), the IP of it and other information.

[image]

What does each value on the Network Graph means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what the abbreviations mean:

- **IND**: Interpolation Delay
- **LAT**: Latency
- **PNG**: Ping
- **RTT**: Round Trip Time
- **SIM**: Simulation
- **CMDQ**: Command Queue
- **PPS IN**: Packets per Second Incoming
- **PPS OUT**: Packets per Second Outgoing
- **LOSS IN**: Incoming Packet Loss
- **LOSS OUT**: Outgoing Packet Loss

I also found this YouTube video that goes into great details explaining what each little thing on the Network Graph.

Comment: There is a barely visible green 13ms text between RTT and CMDQ, the only one that you missed :)

Comment: Also: If you can, try to add some explanations for those that don't know the meanings. (for example, I know what a Packet Loss is but others might not)

Comment: @Lemon I think that sort of departs from your original question tho, since explanation for the abbreviations was given. Regarding the green line, I don't have the foggiest and I wasn't able to find anything regarding that line online.